# listbox Multiple select items go to top

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

am using a listbox with multiple selection control. Now am having 200 names in list box. suppose i select no of employee 50,76,34,65,95 etc. First am select 50 and hold ctrl key and select 76 means its go to the top of the first name. I have listbox with in update panel with triger'. but it post back for each selection.please help me to fix this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `ListBox.AutoPostback` to false does it then behave as you want it to?

Comment: But i want to get the count of selected item count when am selecting each name. what i do.

Comment: @Fernando: please post some code. and if you want count of selected item you can use jquery to get seleted item count [ var selectedValue = $('#listboxID :selected').length ]

Answer (score 0):

your List Box is placed inside the updatepanel with trigger. it won't postback for each selection, it is posted back due to trigger. you can select multiple items by setting the long duration between the triggers.

Comment: How can i set this please help me to do this